# I'm trying to use volume scatter node on an OBJECT material in EEVEE, but every time it gets applied on WORLD

Tags: volumetrics

In the first image I've deleted the principle BSDF and added the volume scatter node
[image]
And on the second image even though I've applied volume scatter on the cube, it gets applied on whole world
[image]

why is this happening is there any settings I've to change?

Comment: please show us your blend file. i tried it out - it works. Which Blender version do you use?

Comment: [edit] your question and add an image that shows the material settings for the world.

Comment: Maybe your material is shared by a bigger object encompassing your scene